# Ckeditor does not appear after refreshing div

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to assing an initial value to a ckeditor using jQuery adapter on php. However, whenever jquery refreshes the div, in which there is a ckeditor, ckeditor dissapears. 
this is how I defined the editor:

```
$ckeditor = new CKEditor();
$ckeditor->basePath  = 'ckeditor/' ;
CKFinder::SetupCKEditor( $ckeditor, 'ckfinder/' ) ;
$config['height'] = '300';
$initialValue = $result['field'];
$ckeditor->editor('CKeditor1', $initialValue, $config);
```

And here is the jquery part:

```
function myfunction(id) {
   jQuery('#mydiv').showLoading();
   var variable = "id=" + id;
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "requiredpage.php",
       data: yol,
       error: function () {
           alert('Errorrr!');
       },
       success: function (data) {
           jQuery('#mydiv').hideLoading();
           $('#mydiv').html(data);
       }
   });
}
```

Thanks all in advanced.

Comment: I'd imagine that you're obliterating the editor when you call .html()

Comment: You want to change ckeditor data after ajax is executed? Here "$('#mydiv').html(data);" you have changed content of mydiv element so editor will be lost.

Comment: I have list of some records and below that list I have some input boxes and ckeditor. User can either create new record or edit an existing one. Whenever I clicked edit which is next to each record, other inputboxes fill with the records but ckeditor disappears.

Answer (score 0):

CKeditor reworks the DIV, and jQuery does it too. But since jQuery knows nothing of CKEditor structure, it destroys the editor functionality.

Have a look here: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/CKEditor/